# Removing query string affecting php $_GET

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I was looking for a way to remove the query string entirely to make sure the URLs are nice and tidy as much as possible, but I found [this forum post](http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=12096) and it says that it will not be useful

> *then those query string pages will not be accessible*

- So my general question is will this affect PHP's `$_GET` variable in some way?

In my application I am forming my URLs like this:

> example.com/module/controller/action/arg1/value1/../..

Where arg1 and value1 are NOT a masked query string representation, they are other specific keys for the request.

- Is it possible to have any problems with the structure mentioned above when I remove the query string?

**EDIT:**

I am re-routing all requests going to the application, that do not exists as file and/or folders (couldn't think of better way to say it) to my index.php, which is the entry point of my application. From there the application parses the directory part and does the routing internally(using the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, not that I am not looking for alternative way in doing this I know I could use the `parse_url();` function).

When I have URL like this:

> example.com/module/controller/action/arg1/value1?get_arg1=value1&get_arg2=value2

the value1 gets buggy and the URLs are way too ugly in my standarts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - So my general question is will this affect PHP's $_GET variable in some way?
> - Is it possible to have any problems with the structure mentioned above when I remove the query string?

The forum poster wants to remove the query string and all traces of data passed to the page *completely*. This is a bad idea since their site will no longer work.

What you are proposing takes what was normally in the query string and puts it into the path info instead. This is acceptable provided you 1) use a URL rewriter to change the path info back into a query string on the server-side, or 2) modify your code to use the path info instead.

Comment: What your answer states in 1) and 2) is already done. I am parsing the path for internal use and I am rewriting the requests as needed atm. The only thing is that I do not want to show the query string after the ``?`` so to transform example.com/module/controller/action/arg1/value1?get_arg1=value1&get_arg2=value2 in to example.com/module/controller/action/arg1/value1 and have  get_arg1=value1&get_arg2=value2 in the $_GET variable

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your URL rewriter.

Comment: Could you evaluate a little bit more what is a problem in my application ?

Comment: Not without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36120/discussion-between-daghostman-dimitrov-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)